# Add button above RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add `Button` above `RecyclerView`, but it doesn't work :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#008080"
tools:context=".fragmentUsers">
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ｓｅｎｄ ｕｓ"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rc"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rc"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loadingtext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="txt"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your code with below code, that will help you what you want

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#008080"
>
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/your_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ｓｅｎｄ ｕｓ"
    />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_below="@+id/your_id"
    android:id="@+id/rc"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loadingtext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="txt"/>
```